# What is the threshold for top to label a process as idle

Tags: process, cpu, top, load-average

With the `top` command I can toggle, whether to list idle processes or not. What is the CPU usage limit for a process to show up as idle or non-idle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `man top`:

> When this toggle is Off, tasks that have not used any CPU since the last update will not be displayed.

Thus the "CPU usage limit for a process to show up as idle or non-idle" is anything greater than 0.

Comment: So, if I run top in batch mode using only 1 iteration, then idle means, that the process has not used the CPU at all in the delay time of top.

Comment: That is correct